# Containable behavior is not working across the Plugins in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

I am working on cakephp 3.0 and i like to use plugins and i wrote my application in the form of plugins and my problem is that cakephp 3.0 doesn't allow containable behavior across the plugin and it's show **Model is not associated**

I have created two plugins Auth and Comments:

**Controllers in Auth Plugin**

- UsersController
- RolesCOntroller

**Models in Auth Plugin**

In cakephp 3.0 models are changes as compare to 2.x they have Entity and ModelTable so Auth Model Tables are below

- UsersTable
- RolesTable

**UsersTable:-**

```
            <?php
        namespace Auth\Model\Table;

        use Auth\Model\Entity\User;
        use Cake\ORM\Query;
        use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
        use Cake\ORM\Table;
        use Cake\Validation\Validator;


        class UsersTable extends Table
        {
            public function initialize(array $config)
            {
                parent::initialize($config);

                $this->table('users');
                $this->displayField('name');
                $this->primaryKey('id');

                $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

                $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
                    'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
                    'joinType' => 'INNER',
                    'className' => 'Auth.Roles'
                ]);
                $this->hasMany('Comments', [
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'className' => 'Auth.Comments'
                ]);
                $this->hasMany('Contents', [
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'className' => 'Auth.Contents'
                ]);
            }


            public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
            {
                return $validator;
            }


            public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
            {
                $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
                $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
                $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['role_id'], 'Roles'));
                return $rules;
            }}
```

**RolesTable**

```
        <?php
        namespace Auth\Model\Table;

        use Auth\Model\Entity\Role;
        use Cake\ORM\Query;
        use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
        use Cake\ORM\Table;
        use Cake\Validation\Validator;


        class RolesTable extends Table
        {

            public function initialize(array $config)
            {
                parent::initialize($config);

                $this->table('roles');
                $this->displayField('id');
                $this->primaryKey('id');

                $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

                $this->hasMany('Users', [
                    'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
                    'className' => 'Auth.Users'
                ]);
            }

            public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
            {


                return $validator;
            }
        }
```

**CommentsPlugin**

**Controllers in Comments Plugin**

- CommentsController

**Models in Comments Plugin**

- CommentsTable

  ```
      <?php
      namespace Comments\Model\Table;

      use Cake\ORM\Query;
      use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
      use Cake\ORM\Table;
      use Cake\Validation\Validator;
      use Comments\Model\Entity\Comment;

      class CommentsTable extends Table
      {

          public function initialize(array $config)
          {
              parent::initialize($config);

              $this->table('comments');
              $this->displayField('name');
              $this->primaryKey('id');

              $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
              $this->addBehavior('Tree');

              $this->belongsTo('ParentComments', [
                  'className' => 'Comments.Comments',
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
              ]);
              $this->belongsTo('Users', [
                  'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                  'className' => 'Comments.Users'
              ]);
              $this->belongsTo('Contents', [
                  'foreignKey' => 'content_id',
                  'joinType' => 'INNER',
                  'className' => 'Comments.Contents'
              ]);
              $this->hasMany('ChildComments', [
                  'className' => 'Comments.Comments',
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
              ]);
          }

          public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
          {

              return $validator;
          }

          public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
          {
              $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
              $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['parent_id'],       'ParentComments'));
              $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));
              $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['content_id'], 'Contents'));
              return $rules;
          }
      }
  ```

Now i wanna get all users with their related data in comments controller and i am doing like this :

```
    $this->Comments->Users->find('all',[
       'contain'=>['Roles']
    ])
```

and it's show's error **Users is not associated with Roles** but it's working in old version of cakephp(2.7)

[Users is not associated with Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yypIb.png)

Comment: There is no containable behavior anymore, contain is now part of the ORM, and it generally works fine with plugin models/associations. I'd suggest to start debugging what the very specific error message tells you, check why `Comments.Users` and `Comments.Contents` are using auto-tables (instances of `\Cake\ORM\Table`) instead of concrete instances of your table classes! To me it looks like you'd want to use `Auth.Users` instead of `Comments.Users`.

Comment: yes containable behavior is now a part of ORM and i my case it's working fine as normal src not in form of plugins . it is working with all models which are belongs to a single plugin but when i try to use **orm** out side the plugin mean in other plugin the containable behavior not work.`$this->Comments->Users->find('all')` working fine gives all users but i want to get all users relational data too. for now i dont know where i am wrong tell me the solution .Thanks

Comment: That's all nice, but again, look at what the error message says, and check what I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Ooh now i understand ** thank's ** man you have solved my problem :)

Comment: @ndm perhaps you can create an answer from your comment, so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered list.

Comment: @InigoFlores If I knew what exactly solved the problem I may... if it was the "typo", ie `Comments` instead of `Auth`, then it would be better to close this question, as it's unlikely to be of help for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no containable behavior anymore, contain is now part of the ORM, and it generally works fine with plugin models/associations. I'd suggest to start debugging what the very specific error message tells you, check why Comments.Users and Comments.Contents are using auto-tables (instances of \Cake\ORM\Table) instead of concrete instances of your table classes! To me it looks like you'd want to use Auth.Users instead of Comments.Users .

I copied this content from first comment of the question writen by @ndm